# CMake and Continuous Integration with several dependent projects

Tags: continuous-integration, cmake, ctest

I currently configure CMake/CTest for CI. Everything works fine except for the following:
We have several projects which depend on each other. In our toplevel build script, though, they are just being built in the right order. During CI, for each of the projects I just do a "make Continuous" in the build directory of the respective project. However when, say a header file is updated in one project only this project gets build after "make Continuous". Another dependent project which uses the same include files is not rebuild during "make Continuous" because in this project no updates occur.

So my question: Is there any way to force the build step to be done during "make Continuous", independent of the result of the svn update?

Any other ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

add_dependencies will work for your case.

```
add_dependencies(target-name depend-target1 depend-target2 ...)
```

See also

http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:add_dependencies